# Is it technically possible to have ns records external to webhost for reduncy on shared hosting

Tags: web-hosting

The way I know commercial hosting on shared servers is like the following:

```
    1)ns records with web host 
    2)I have to configure the domain with my registrar to 
have the ns records hosted by web host
```

But how will it work if I wanted the ns records to hosted by my registrar for redundency. How does the web server know which site to serve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes, certainly. Web hosting and DNS services are two completely separate functions. Yes, they *can* coexist on the same server, but they don't *need* to.

Just point your domain's `NS` records to whomever you want and then create an `A` record pointing to your webserver. When your browser makes a request to the webserver, it submits as part of the `HTTP` `GET` request a `host` header with the hostname of the website it's requesting. The server then responds appropriately. In fact, this would all still happen even if the webserver was not set up with proper DNS resolvers.